# How to get machine account from which the user login to my application?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to get the user machine account from which he access the application in the case of `Form authentication` .

I use the following method but it doesn't get the required data:

```
protected string[] TrackUser()
{
    System.Web.HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
    string IP = context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
    string compName = (Dns.GetHostEntry(Request.ServerVariables["remote_addr"]).HostName);
    string account = Request.ServerVariables["AUTH_USER"];
    string[] user_network_data = new string[3];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(IP))
    {
        string[] addresses = IP.Split(',');
        if (addresses.Length != 0)
        {
            IP = addresses[0];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        IP = context.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    }
    user_network_data[0] = IP;
    user_network_data[1] = compName;
    user_network_data[2] = account;
    return user_network_data;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the account the user logged into the machine with (e.g. domain\username) or are you trying to get the AD account that the physical machine is joined to the domain with (which is irrespective of the user currently logged into it)?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're just grabbing the wrong initial information from the request.  Try these:

```
string IP = context.Request.UserHostAddress;
string compName = context.Request.UserHostName;
string account = context.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name;
```

I think the rest of your code should work fine once you have the right data to start off with.

Comment: it works okay locally but it brings the server data when i publish !!

Comment: @just_name Hmmm, could you be more specific?  Is the user name still correct when you publish?

Comment: `context.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name` brings the account of the server i published on